# Prevent Excel Chart Data Labels overlapping

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel dashboard with line charts containing data labels. Specifically, we are only using the data labels at the rightmost end of the lines, and the labels consist of the Series name and final value. By changing a dropdown, the dashboard is automatically updated to give 19 different dashboards.
The problem is that we can't work out any way of preventing the labels overlapping.
Everything else on the dashboard can be made to automatically update nicely, except for this.
Can anybody think of a way to do this? E.g. plugin or macro.

Comment: Why don't remove labels and insert a legend?

Comment: toc: that's what i recommended. The client wants to see the name   and final value right next to the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at John Peltier's page on this topic:  http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/LabelLastPoint.html

Comment: This is a great resource for marking the last label on a chart. While it won't stop data labels overlapping, I believe there is no established way of doing this, and it would require custom coding. So I'll award this answer.

Comment: To prevent data label overlapping, one would have to write code that looked for labels that overlapped, then figure out which way to move the labels to reduce or remove the overlap without causing overlap with other labels. I've had a go at it, and it's rather tricky.

Comment: An even better article I've written is [Prevent Overlapping Data Labels in Excel Charts](https://peltiertech.com/prevent-overlapping-data-labels-in-excel-charts/), which is designed to adjust the vertical positions of data labels for points at a given category, such as the last point in each series.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do is under Data Label use Data Callout and you can move the individual data label and the label wound still point to the original point in the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your Chart Area Marginally bigger than the Plot Area.

0. Choose your worst dashboard (longest axis labels)
1. Click the Plot Area.
2. Reduce the size of your Plot area from bottom so that you have extra space at the bottom. (i.e. Chart Area is bigger than the Plot Area by some extra margin)
3. Now click your horizontal axis labels.
4. Click Reduce Font (Or Increase Font) button

The text will automatically wrap to fit in the available space.
And this should work for the other dashboards as the other labels are smaller than this.